# Google maps v2 on android emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I am facing an issue right now so i appeal to all you awesome android developers to help me out with this issue. There is a specific need in my application to run Google maps v2 on an emulator. Have been searching here and there but of no use.  Can someone properly tell me how to run Google maps v2 successfully on android emulator. Have tried both google Api version as well as the pure android one(installing play store apk and play services) but none of them are working well.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Not working well means???

Comment: It means that map is not showing in Google api emulator and not even opening up in pure android one.

Comment: your using android studio or eclipse??

Comment: Would need some code and configuration details that you can share in order to figure out the issue. For step by step guide you can refer to this tutorial http://hmkcode.com/run-google-map-v2-on-android-emulator/

Comment: After a well R&D came to the final decision that if we have to run google maps best approach, time saving and convenient is to run on a physical device.

Comment: But cheers to you guys who tried helping me out!!!!